# sqlmap injection point in POST data

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, injection, sqlmap

I am currently doing a blackbox test on a web application for training purposes. It's a personal project.

In addition to my manual testing process, I used an automated scanner for detecting obvious vulnerabilities. While this tool only found some basic issues, it also detected a potential SQLi vulnerability which I did not notice before. I am able to reproduce the error using Burp, but I am still not able to extract database data manually. Because of that, I gave sqlmap a shot.

Before I come to my actual question, let me give you some details:

The vulnerability seems to exist in a login form. When the following sequence is POSTed to the form

```
password=letmein&username=1%c0%00xa7%c0%a2
```

a mysql error is returned:

*Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given*

I have narrowed the sequence down to the byte *%c0*. This urlencoded value leads to the warning. So far, I am not sure why exactly this value leads to the warning.

The sqlmap setup looks like this:

```
 sqlmap -u http://thehost/include/login.php --method POST --data "password=letmein&username=1%c0%00xa7%c0%a2" -p "username" --dbms=mysql
```

Which generates requests/payloads in the following form:

```
 [PAYLOAD] 1%c0%00xa7%c0%a2)).("(,)'(
 [TRAFFIC OUT] HTTP request [#3]:
 POST /include/login.php HTTP/1.1
 Host: thehost
 Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
 Accept: */*
 Content-length: 70
 Connection: close
```

What I would like to do/try is change the injection point within the POST data. Is this possible? I know it is possible to specify an injection point within a GET request. Additionally, does anybody have an idea why the injected *%c0* byte messes up the query?

thanks

Comment: Do you mind sharing the relevant parts of the source code?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the source code/mysql query (blackbox test). It's a training environment.

Comment: From some reading it seems '%c0%a2' is decoded into a bad sequence, I've not yet worked out exactly what it decodes to though.

Comment: So I think I worked it out to decode as \\* but I might be completely wrong.

Comment: @djsmiley2k thanks for your input! I haven't figured it out either. The only idea I had so far was to check http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html which pointed me to the following codepoint/character combinations: U+00C0, 0xC0, %C3 %80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the injection point, but `0xc0a2` is a another way to encode the **"** character using the UTF-8 character encoding. What happens here is that the page script incorrectly strips "dangerous" characters *before* converting the encoding. You can actually insert all restricted characters this way. Just split the 7-bit binary value of the ascii code in two and encode it like this: `1100000x 10xxxxxx`

Answer (score 0):

SQLmap works in a heuristic way, firstly it learns about difference about good and bad response from the application, then you have to introduce a real value for `username` parameter to get a good response, SQLmap will analyze the responses after that it will inject sql commands to detect a possible SQL Injection. Your SQLmap command must be something like this:

```
sqlmap -u http://thehost/include/login.php --data "password=letmein&username=this_is_a_real_username" -p "username" --dbms=mysql
```

The option `--method POST` is not neccesary, SQLmap knows it's a request POST when you use the option `--data`.

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried your approach before - the problem is that sqlmap does not detect an injectionpoint/does not detect an injection vulnerability. I am only able to trigger the mysql error using a sequence that contains *%c0* (or maybe another encoded character that generates a conflict when used with the existing database query). I am still trying to figure out why/how the warning is returned to the user.

Comment: You could use the options --risk and --level, also you can use the option --tamper and specify different injection techniques for MySQL, for example: --tamper tamper/space2mysqldash.py,tamper/space2mysqlblank.py

Answer (score 0):

Referring this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1

I believe it's not problem with the injection, rather the passed parameters might not be giving out any result and the application is trying to read the **false** value returned due to empty results.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I run into this one quite often. I am not sure if it is exploitable.

It so happens that when you use mysql_real_escape_string() in your code (AND YOU SHOULD!) before passing the input to a database query, a certain encoding is used.

I believe in this case the %c0 is not escaped, causes the execute_query() to trow an error (returning false, instead of the expected row)

%c0 in UTF-8 (which the program uses) is "À" and that breaks the query as it has no value in UTF-8 and as a result a "\x00" is injected. Everything breaks then..
I have been trying to figure out a way to make this work to my advantage but so far, I have had no luck!